# Angular Bootstrap if tab is active, hide external div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

Is there a way to detect if a specific tab is active and then hiding a div outside all tabs when it is active?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/b9O9S7JxxgzhQKcKONkn?p=preview

```
  <div class="border">
    Hide me when Tab #3 is active.
  </div>
  <hr>
  <form name="outerForm" class="tab-form-demo">
    <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Tab #1">
        <ng-form name="nestedForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="model.name"/>
          </div>
        </ng-form>
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="1" heading="Tab #2">
        Some Tab Content
      </uib-tab>

      <uib-tab index="2" heading="Tab #3">
        More Tab Content
      </uib-tab>

    </uib-tabset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-hide` to your functionality like

```
<div class="border" ng-hide="activeForm==2">
    Hide me when Tab #3 is active.
</div>
```

Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QRlM1o6nBj1C0nNZqhS4?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the value of activeForm, which stores the value of the index(tab)

```
<div class="border" ng-show="activeForm != 2" >
    Hide me when Tab #3 is active.
  </div>
```